# Get column names from DataFrame or JuliaDB table

Tags: dataframe, julia, juliadb

How do I get the column names from a `DataFrame` object or JuliaDB `IndexedTable` object? Is this possible?

---

Reproducible Code:

```py
using JuliaDB
import DataFrames
DF = DataFrames

# CREATES AN EXAMPLE TABLE WITH JULIADB

colnames = [:samples, :A, :B, :C, :D]
primary_key = [:samples]
coltypes = [Int[], Float64[],Float64[],Float64[],Float64[]]
sample_sizes = [100,200,300]
example_values = (1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)

mytable = table(coltypes..., names=colnames, pkey=primary_key) # initialize empty table

# add some data to table
for i in sample_sizes
    example_values = (i, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)
    table_params = [(col=>val) for (col,val) in zip(colnames, example_values)]

    push!(rows(mytable), (; table_params...)) # add row
    mytable = table(mytable, pkey = primary_key, copy = false) # sort rows by primary key
end
mytable = table(unique(mytable), pkey=primary_key) # remove duplicate rows which don't exist

# MAKES A DATAFRAME FROM JULIADB TABLE

df = DF.DataFrame(mytable)
```

For instance, given the above code, how would you check with a conditional if there's a column `:E` in either `mytable` or `df`, (for the purposes of adding such a column if it doesn't exist yet)?

Ultimately, I'm looking for the Julia equivalent of the following Python code:

```py
if 'E' in df.columns:
     # ...
else:
     # ...
```

Comment: what about `names(df)`?

Comment: That works for DataFrames. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `df` is a data frame you can write:

```
if "E" in names(df)
...
```

(in JuliaDB.jl it would be `JuliaDB.colnames`)

but a faster (in terms of run-time and available for data frames option is:

```
if hasproperty(df, :E)
...
```

A bit slower, but useful in other cases is (it also works for JuliaDB.jl but first you have to load Tables.jl and write `Tables.columnindex` instead):

```
if columnindex(df, :E) != 0
...
```

The last example `columnindex` is probably most complex the way it works is described in its documentation:

```
help?> columnindex
search: columnindex

  Tables.columnindex(table, name::Symbol)

  Return the column index (1-based) of a column by name in a table with a
  known schema; returns 0 if name doesn't exist in table

  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  given names and a Symbol name, compute the index (1-based) of the name in
  names
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. This solves my problem. That said, though, none of these methods work on a JuliaDB IndexedTable (I'd have to convert it to a DataFrame first). Am I correct in assuming that JuliaDB is still very much a work in progress?

Comment: Sorry for this - I was writing from my head what should work for Tables.jl :(. I will fix in the answer what you can do.

Comment: I now fixed it. Unfortunately JuliaDB.jl is not fully compliant with Tables.jl interface yet which caused confusion.